# cakephp auth login issue, only white screen appear

Tags: cakephp

I’ve created a small cakePHP application that uses the auth component to manage an admin section for changes.

The problem I’m having ‘only in the production environment’ is that after I login all I can see is a blank white screen. I should be redirected to a ‘dashboard’ view. This blank screen is also what I get with all other ‘admin’ prefixed views that require a logged in user, thus the auth component.

What is strange about this are two things, (1) this works fine in the local host and (2) this application is a copy of one that works fine in both the local host and production.

What I’ve done to try and resolve this is:

- Checked the previous application copy; nothing different found
- Checked that the passwords were hashed
- Checked that the .htaccess file was uploaded in ASCII format (suggested by the host)

Any help with this is appreciated.

Ideally I’d like to understand how to trouble shoot this type of problem.

Thanks, Prasad

Comment: Look in the PHP/Apache error logs.

Answer (score 0):

Possible things to do/check...

- Turn on debug in your app/config/bootstrap.php file.
- Clean out caches in each of the directories in app/tmp/cache.
- Make sure you've properly created ACL stuff.
- Check contents of app/tmp/logs/error.log and app/tmp/logs/debug.log.
- Check /var/log/httpd/error_log (or wherever your web server makes its own logs for errors and php errors).